# AOSP 13: Manifest merge problem due to androidx-startup duplication

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-source

I'm compiling an vendor system application in aosp13 code, but facing following manifest merge error.

```
manifest/AndroidManifest.xml.fixed:42:13-70 Error:
        Attribute provider#androidx.startup.InitializationProvider@authorities value=(androidx.lifecycle.extensions.androidx-startup) from AndroidManifest.xml:42:13-70
        is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:34:13-70 value=(androidx.appcompat.androidx-startup).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:authorities"' to <provider> element at AndroidManifest.xml.fixed:40:9-51:20 to override.
```

Here androidx.lifecycle.extensions & androidx.appcompat both are included as static libraries.

Same code is compiling successfully in Aosp12 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add below <provider> code into your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application>
    <provider xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        tools:replace="android:authorities" />
</application>
```

Comment: Thank you @cbybear0
Also I could resolve this error in another two ways
1. converting mk file to bp
2. by adding below lines to application tag
android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
        tools:remove="android:authorities"